# can't load phpmyadmin after installing wamp

Tags: php, mysql, apache, wampserver

I am trying to install latest version of wamp server 2.2 on my local machine. I had IIS running on port 80 so I installed wamp on port 8080, everything is working fine except phpmyadmin which just givnig me blank page with 'connection was timed out'or 'page cannot be displayed message, I have tried disabling IIS but nothing changed. I also tested the php and mysql connection both are working fine and other alias sqlbuddy and webgrind are also working.. I've also tested xampp as well but having the same problem with wamp? any help would be appreciated thanks.

Here is the apache error log update everytime I access phpmyadmin...

```
[Mon Jun 04 16:15:16.701238 2012] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1852:tid 392] AH00428: Parent: child process exited with status 255 -- Restarting.
[Mon Jun 04 16:15:16.763242 2012] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1852:tid 392] AH00455: Apache/2.4.2 (Win64) PHP/5.4.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Jun 04 16:15:16.763242 2012] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1852:tid 392] AH00456: Server built: May 13 2012 19:54:49
[Mon Jun 04 16:15:16.763242 2012] [core:notice] [pid 1852:tid 392] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\wamp\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.2\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.2'
[Mon Jun 04 16:15:16.764242 2012] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1852:tid 392] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 476
[Mon Jun 04 16:15:17.190266 2012] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 476:tid 288] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
```

Comment: Have you checked the error logs, not sure where they are with wamp

Comment: yes but it seems nothing particularly wrong with phpmyadmin

Answer (score 4):

You can change through the WAMP settings

1. Go to your wamp folder and edit wampmanager.tpl
2. Find the phpmyadmin reference (localhost/phpmyadmin) and add port 8080 (localhost:8080/phpmyadmin/)
3. Restart wamp

(This assumes that the rest of WAMP is already listening on port 8080 - otherwise you need to add a listerner on that port in httpd.conf as well, plus change other references in wampmanager.tpl . But as you say that's working I assume you'rve already done that)

Comment: thanks for answering robbie, I just add :8080 on wampmanager.tpl but still having same problem. :S yea I've already added it on httpd.conf.

Comment: You have saved + restarted WAMP? It should do the trick as it really sounds like phpMyAdmin is redirecting to port 80 (IIS) and then timing out. Another solution (actually the one I use) is to toggle IIS / Apache on and off - instructions here http://www.sitepoint.com/run-apache-iis-same-pc-2/. But that won't solve your immediate problem (that should be solvable).

Comment: Good resource thanks, but still can't solve this. I uninstalled IIS and every web related things like .NET and stuff..and I tried to uninstall and reinstall wamp too, now apache itself is working on port 80 and everything is running by default.. but phpmyadmin.

Comment: Thanks. Worked for me

Answer (score 2):

This seems to have been answered, but a simple method that worked for me, on Windows 7. Was to simply right click on the WAMP icon, select tools, find "Port Used by Apache2", test port 80, and if that comes up with a, "already used by X application" then select the "Use another Port other than 80" option.

I selected 8080 and it works fine.

You can then use: http://localhost:8080/phpmyadmin/ to access phpMyAdmin.

If 8080 doesn't work, then check to see what application may be using it, and exit that app, or just try another port.

**What Port 80 comes up with if it's already used**
[image: I guess exiting IIS would make sense]

**This is what it should look like**
[image]

This setup works for me, so I hope it helps!

Comment: Yes, Your answer is more appropriate & helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Steps for phpmyadmin:

1. type in browser: localhost:3306/phpmyadmin
2. it will open a line ( i did not understand what that line means :-) )
3. now dont close your browser and type : localhost/phpmyadmin
4. then it will work.

I do the same

Answer (score 0):

I changed both *"wampmanager.ini"* and *"wampmanager.tpl"* using steps mentioned by ***Robbie*** and it's working fine on port 8080. (If you still see Access denied error, make sure to clear browser cache and refresh browser page.)